# Kick command with reason

Tags: command, bots, discord, discord.js

I created a kick command with reason, but it doesn't kick the member, I don't have any errors...
Also, why when I send the command, it deletes it?

I tried to fix it myself, but still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Here my code:

```
client.on('message', message => { 
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "kick")) { 
     if(message.channel.type === 'DM') { 
    message.channel.send('This command can use only in guide'); 
    return; 
  }; 
  if(!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) { 
    const KickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("YELLOW")
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setDescription("Sorry, but you don't have the permission to use the kick command.")
    message.channel.send(KickEmbed); 
    return; 
  }; 
  let mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first();
  if(!mentionMember) { 
    const ErrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('YELLOW')
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setDescription('**Usage:** `y!kick <@user> or ID` You need to mention an user!')
    message.channel.send(ErrEmbed); 
                      return; 
                     };
        let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    if(!args.lenght) {
      const ReasonError = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('YELLOW')
      .setAuthor(message.author.username)
      .setDescription('Before kicking this member, you need to provide a reason of your kick.')
      message.channel.send(ReasonError)
      return;
    };
  let authorHighestRole = message.member.roles.highest.position; 
  let mentionHighestRole = mentionMember.roles.highest.position; 
  if(mentionHighestRole >= authorHighestRole) { 
    message.channel.send('You can`t kick members with equal or higher position'); 
    return; 
  }; 
  if(!mentionMember.kickable) {
    message.channel.send('I have no permissions to kick this user'); 
    return 
  }; 
  mentionMember.kick() 
    .then(() => message.channel.send(`Kicked ${mentionMember.tag} with reason: ${args}`)) 
    .catch(console.error); 
}
          }
);
```

Comment: You spelled 'args.length' wrong. Might want to fix that

Comment: Ok so now, it works, but only for kick not with reason part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look at docs before posting:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick

But anyways:

`<Member>.kick(Reason)`, it's just a string you pass in.

Also args looks like an array so you can't just use `args` inside of a string, try `args.join(" ")`. (Inside of `message.channel.send("Kicked...")`)

All in all here's the change:

So `mentionMember.kick()` => `mentionMember.kick(args.join(" "))`